# Remove unwanted top space from QLPreviewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, qlpreviewcontroller

In my application I have used a QLPreviewController to display some pdf files. Everything works fine, but there is an unwanted space in the top of content of QLPreviewController and couldn't find a way to remove it.

**This is how I wrote it.** (Please note that I am new to Xamarin.iOS and QLPreviewController)

```
public partial class ReportsViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        //Customize navigation bar for QLPreviewController
        if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0)) // There is a bug with barTintColor on QLPreviewController for iOS 11 if you are showing it via presentViewController: animated:
        {
            var color = UIColor.FromRGB(red: 23, green: 61, blue: 86).CGColor;
            var rect = new CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0);
            var alpha = color.Alpha;
            var opaque = alpha == 1;
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.Size, opaque, 0);
            var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            context.SetFillColor(color);
            context.FillRect(rect);
            var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(QLPreviewController)).SetBackgroundImage(image, UIBarMetrics.Default);

        }
        else // If iOS version is below 11.0
        {
            UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(QLPreviewController)).BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0f);
        }

        UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(QLPreviewController)).BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
        UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(QLPreviewController)).TintColor = UIColor.White;

        var reportSavedPath = "path to pdf file";
        var reportName = "Report name";
        var previewController = new QLPreviewController();
        var url = new NSUrl(reportSavedPath, true);
        var _dataSource = new PreviewControllerSource(this, url, reportName);
        previewController.DataSource = _dataSource;
        PresentViewController(previewController, true, completionHandler: null);
    }
}

public partial class ReportsViewController : UIViewController
{
    class PreviewControllerSource : QLPreviewControllerDataSource
    {
        ReportsViewController _parentClass = null;
        NSUrl _url = null;
        string _title = null;

        public PreviewControllerSource(ReportsViewController parentClass, NSUrl url, string title)
        {
            _parentClass = parentClass;
            _url = url;
            _title = title;
        }

        public override nint PreviewItemCount(QLPreviewController controller)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override IQLPreviewItem GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController controller, nint index)
        {
            return new PreviewItem { title = _title, url = _url };
        }
    }
    public class PreviewItem : QLPreviewItem
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public NSUrl url { get; set; }
        public override string ItemTitle { get { return title; } }
        public override NSUrl ItemUrl { get { return url; } }
    }
}
```

**This is how it looks like when the pdf is loaded**

[image]

Can someone please help me to get this unwanted space removed?

Comment: Could you try a different PDF File of a different dimension and see if the unwanted space is the same amount? Also, which iOS version are you running into that error?

Comment: @Saamer I already tried with different different pdfs. But the space remains for all of them. Im using iOS 12.2

Comment: var rect = new CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0);
What would happen if you reduced these values to 0.1 ?

Comment: @Saamer It didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea about why you have to `Customize navigation bar for QLPreviewController` in your code. I removed it and it works perfect.

I would give you two ways to get rid of the unwanted sapce:

1.remove the code:

```
//UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(QLPreviewController)).SetBackgroundImage(image, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

2.if you really need the code to Customize navigation bar, add this line of code before `PresentViewController`:

```
//Add this line before PresentViewController
UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(QLPreviewController)).SetBackgroundImage(null, UIBarMetrics.Default);

PresentViewController(previewController, true, completionHandler: null);
```

**Update:**

Spent the whole afternoon and only find a solution not so perfect. First, I would like to say that the `navigationBar` of your `viewController` and the `navigationBar` of `QLPreviewController` are two different bars.

To set the navigationbar color, you can simply set it in `AppDelegate`, this will affect the whole `navigationBar` color in your project.:

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0f);
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackOpaque;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;


        return true;
    }
```

To change the `navigationbarColor` of `QLPreviewControl`, you can use the code in `test` function:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{

    QLPreviewController previewController;

    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
        this.ExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false;
        this.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;

        string path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("myPdf.pdf","");
        var reportName = "Report name";
        previewController = new QLPreviewController();
        var url = new NSUrl(path, true);
        var _dataSource = new PreviewControllerSource(this, url, reportName);
        previewController.DataSource = _dataSource;

        this.NavigationController.PresentViewController(previewController, true, test);

    }

    public void test() {

            var firstChild = previewController.ChildViewControllers[0];

            if (firstChild is UINavigationController)
            {
                var naviVc = firstChild as UINavigationController;
                naviVc.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Red ;
            }
        }
}
```

The only thing that is not so perfect is that the `test` function will call until the presenting completed, so you would see the default color of navigationBar a while and then it will change to the color you want.

If you use a push action instead of modal, you can call `test` function inside the `WillShowViewController(UINavigationController navigationController, [Transient] UIViewController viewController, bool animated)`:

```
public class naviDeleagte : UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    public override void WillShowViewController(UINavigationController navigationController, [Transient] UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
    {
        //call test here if you use a push instead of modal
    }
}
```

I uploaded my sample here and you can check it:[navigationBar-color-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/navigationBar-color-xamarin.forms)

Comment: The thing is I need to keep the navigation bar color same in every view. So 2nd option won't work :(

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort friend. I will try this out. sorry for being late to comment here. Cheers.